# Prettier in VS code wraping

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using prettier in VS code. When I'm Writing something like this:

```
document.getElementById(`current--${activePlayer}`).textContent = currentScore;
```

It's get formatted into

```
  document.getElementById(
    `current--${activePlayer}`
  ).textContent = currentScore;
```

Is there a way to keep it the first way?
Thanks

Comment: try increasing print width in `.prettierrc`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Print Width

You can create a prettier config file in your project and increase the value of print width. The code tends to break in newline when it's length exceeds the default value in your editor.

You can configure the prettier rules in **.prettierrc** file.

```
{
  "printWidth": 100,
}
```